# Why I see the page "_layouts/newsbweb.aspx" after debugging my sitedefiniton?

Tags: 2010, site-definition

I have a SharePoint 2010 portal. The site collection is from the site template "publishing site". I have created a simple site definition like in this tutorials:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxhg-uWxyrs
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276356.aspx

It is a simple webpart with a `datetime` control where you can filter the tasks.

After I finished the building of my site definition, I press on F5 to debug. Then it opens my SharePoint portal in a new window and I see the page "_layouts/newsbweb.aspx". Why I see this page? Do I need first to create a new site?

I was expecting a site like my site definition.

Answer (score 1):

Once Deploy your Site Definition in sharePoint server mean, Site Template Created in SharePoint Server. Once you create new site then only you can access content of Site definition.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/395532/SharePoint-2010-Creating-a-Site-Definition-Using-V

check this link